# file broke after opening within a zend optimize server

Tags: php, zend-optimizer

I have a client that has zend optimizer and loads files by the zend Encoder. I opened up one of the files and reuploaded and everything broke. didnt make any changes.

When I refresh the page, i get a blank page.

I was just curious is there some type of command line i can run to re-encode the file.  I tried re-uploading original files by binary. but when I refreshed the page again it displayed the html and php code within the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Blank page probably means that you have a PHP error. Check the web server error logs or enable display_errors in php.ini.

Comment: ok, well since I reuploaded the file, I no longer get a blank page. I get the actual text in the file including the html tags and php code.

Comment: If you see php code on the page, then its not getting passed through the php compiler. Generally most configurations only compile pages with the extension of .php

Comment: Thanks for the responses by the way. I was able to bring back the blank page with display_errors turned on, still blank. It is blank when I upload as a ascii document and it shows the php code when I upload as a binary. The file is a .php file